# my login is always successful, whether it is correct/wrong username or password

Tags: c#, database, authentication, webforms

The login form is using the patient table to login. Whether I type in correct or wrong username/password it always redirect me to the home page which is index.aspx which means sucessful. For my below code, I select patientID too because I would like to store the patientID in a session.

Comment: It looks to me like there is a problem with `int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());`... doesn't your query return 3 columns but you are storing just one? And because it is returning 3 but you are asking for a single `int id`, your check for `if (id != null)` will never return false?

Comment: It looks to me is uses techniques to build queries that are badly vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked, even when after it's checking passwords correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem :** you need to understand that Valu types will never hold `null`. so checking id against null will always retur `true` hence you are able to login into system in all conditions.

**Solution :** you should have a mechanism where you can identify the actual value of the `ExecuteScalar()`. it will return `null` if incase there are no records.but it wont be converted to int as null so you should first check for null against `ExecuteScalar()` retur value and then if it is not null convert that into integer otherwise assign zero.

Try This:

```
        int id =(cmd.ExecuteScalar()!=null)?Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()):0;
        if (id > 0)
        {
            Session.Add("ID", id);
            Session.Add("pUsername", txtUserName.Text);
            Session.Add("pPassword", txtPassword.Text);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(txtUserName.Text, true);
            Response.Redirect("index.aspx");
        }
```

**EDIT:** Your system allows Empty UserName and Empty Password as Valid credentials as you you have  Id 5 with empty `UserName` and `Password` in above table. so add `UserName` and `Password` for userId 5 so that it wont allow empty username and password.

Comment: It works. If I type incorrect username or password, it will prompt error. But If i type nothing at all for both username and password and click submit, it still redirects me to index.aspx. why? @Sudhakar Tillapudi

Comment: @Jordjmax: yes becuase you have User with Id `5` with empty user name and password in above table. so add `UserName` and `Password` for userId 5 so that it wont allow empty username and password so works perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

an integer in c# is never null. it can be 0 though.

```
int id = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

id will be 0 in case of no record found so this condition

```
if (id != null)
```

will always be true.check if id is not 0 like this

```
if (id <= 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*Disclaimer: This won't fix your issue, but it's too long to leave as comment and important enough to what you're doing I felt justified providing it as an answer.*</sub>

---

The code below is really, **really** bad:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pUsername='" + user + "' AND pPassword='" + pwd + "'  ";
```

You MUST do it this way instead:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT patientID, pUsername, pPassword FROM patient WHERE pUsername= @user and pPassword= @password;"
cmd.Parameters.Add("@user", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 16).Value = user;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = pwd;
```

You **must** use Parameters anywhere you substitute user data into a query. *No Exceptions*. Anything else WILL result in your app being hacked... probably sooner rather than later.

Additionally, it looks like you're storing passwords in plain text. That's nearly as bad as not using parameters. The correct way to store passwords is to prepend a per-user salt to the password and then store a cryptographicly secure hash (bcrypt or scrypt) of the result. When authenticating a user, you perform the same steps on the attempted password and compare the hash values, not the password directly.

Really, you should not be writing authentication code at all. Authentication is one of those things where it's easy to build something that *seems* to work... passes all your tests... but in the end is fundamentally flawed in a subtle way that results in you finding out a year later that you were pwned six months ago. The best course is to always lean as much as possible on the authentication features provided by your platform of choice. In the case of ASP.Net, that means learning and using the [*Membership provider*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.ASPX) features.